# Google Cloud Vision reverse image search fails on Azure App Service because GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS file cannot be found

Tags: azure, google-api, azure-web-app-service, google-cloud-vision, azure-app-service-plans

I am attempting to perform a Google reverse image search using [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) on an Azure app service web app.

I have generated a googleCred.json, which the Google client libraries use in order to construct API requests. Google expects it to be available from an environment variable named GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

The Azure app service that runs the web app has settings that mimic environment variables for the Google client libraries. The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure), and I have successfully set the variable here:

[image]

Furthermore, the googleCred.json file has been uploaded to the app service. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp) I followed to use FTP and FileZilla to upload the file:

[image]

Also, the file permissions are as open as they can be:

[image]

However, when I access the web app in the cloud, I get the following error message:

> Error reading credential file from location D:\site\wwwroot\Statics\googleCred.json: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\site\wwwroot\Statics\googleCred.json'. Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

**What am I doing wrong? How can I successfully use the Google Cloud Vision API on an Azure web app?**

Comment: which language are you writing your code in? C#, Java, something else? Does your code explicitly create GoogleCredential object with something like.. GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(File.OpenRead(authfile));? If possible share some more info/code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is usually thrown when the application is not being **authenticated** correctly due to several reasons such as missing files, invalid credential paths, incorrect environment variables assignations, among other causes.

Based on this, I recommend you to validate that the credential file and file path are being correctly assigned, as well as follow the [Obtaining and providing service account credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) guide in order to **explicitly specify your service account file** directly into your code; In this way, you will be able to set it permanently and verify if you are passing the service credentials correctly.

**Passing the path to the service account key in code example:**

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library.
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Instantiates a client. Explicitly use service account credentials by
// specifying the private key file. All clients in google-cloud-node have this
// helper, see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/blob/master/docs/authentication.md
const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});

// Makes an authenticated API request.
storage
  .getBuckets()
  .then((results) => {
    const buckets = results[0];

    console.log('Buckets:');
    buckets.forEach((bucket) => {
      console.log(bucket.name);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing here since i can't comment, but at a quick glance, is the "D:" in the path necessary?  I assume you uploaded the file to the app service so try with this value for the path "\site\wwwroot\Statics\googleCred.json"